# Camel jms listener not picking up right messages

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Usecase: I would like to pick messages from an http end point and route them to a jms endpoint.

My route configuration looks like:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9080/quote")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .to("stream:out")
            .to(InOut, "wmq:queue:" + requestQueue +
                    "?replyTo=" + responseQueue +
                    "&replyToType=" + replyToType +
                    "&useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true");
```

My understanding is that this way I will get a request-response pattern for the JMS endpoint and correlationId would be the unique identifier to make the response to the corresponding request.
This works well when I have only 1 instance of the application running however when I have more than 1 instances running simultaneously, responses are picked up randomly and not only by the producer.

For example, A and B are 2 instances of the route (and listener) with exact same configuration listening for responses on a shared queue. At times A gets its response but at times it also picks up response for the message produced by B.

Appreciate any help/pointers on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to confirm the application on the other end is replying with responses with different correlationID's properly set?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue was with the use of `replyToType` which was set to `Exclusive` - this resulted in listener picking up everything instead of using jms selectors to match correlation ids.

I changed the value of `replyToType` to `Shared` and its all working fine now.

This is well defined in section "Request-Reply over JMS" at http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Comment: That'd do it =)